# how to read line by line from a given file?

Tags: bash

i wrote a script , and in this script i wrote a function that accepts a parameter which resembles an id , and in the function i read from a given file line by line , the file line format is :

> id_num  name   number_of_brothers  other_people_id (optional)
>   (also there could be as many spaces between each two words and in the start )

for example :

> 236501  james  show  3  234247  234125

(the id numbers must include only 6 digits and the name can have at the end a number, but number of brothers must be between 0-10)
in this example the name is : "james show"
another example:

> 236501  james  show  3  4  234247  234125

this time the name is "james show 3"
now i want to read line by line and see which line start with the given parameter and print the name..

! now in order to read line by line from the given file i used real line and at he end i did `done < "$given_file"`

but when i run the script from bash i get this error :

> syntax error near unexpected token `}'
>   i get this error in the last line of the following function i used in the script :

```
function get_name{
  while read -a line; do
  l=`echo $line`               
  if [[ `grep ^"$1" "$line"` != " " ]]; then  
   l=`cut -d" " -f2-`   
    i=1
    while(( i>0 )) ; do
      if (( ${line[i]}>=0 && $${line[i]}<11 && ( ${line[i+1]} == " " || `get_num ${line[i+1]}` == 6 ))) ; then 
         l=`cut -d " " -f1-i`
         echo "$l"
         break
     fi
    let i++
    done
  fi
  done < "$given_file"

}  ## here i get the error
```

what i am doing wrong in reading from the file ?

Comment: there are too many micro things here. could you give a verbal explanation on what thing you want to check? I can see a number issues in this function already.

Comment: in fact, i don't think you wrote it correctly in many ways. show me what you want and i will point the problems out one by one.

Comment: oh wow i didn't expect to have many problems :( i am gonna update the question explaining

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ would tell you things like "you need a space before `{`".

Comment: @Jack no it's not true. `read -a` gives array.

Comment: i updated the question ..

Comment: so you want to print the person's name?

Comment: i guess `james show` has 3 brothers but why there are only two id's after that?

Comment: The reason for the syntax error is a missing space on your function declaration, before the brace, i.e.:  `function get_name {`

Comment: the id numbers after the number of brothers are random and not for the brothers :\ which is confusing

Comment: yes i want to print it's name

Comment: yes the syntax error was because of the missing space

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I missed that.  I will delete my stupidity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to achieve the work, it's no more than one liner.

```
function get_name {
    sed -n -r "s/^$1 (.*) [0-9]{1,2}( [0-9]{6})*/\1/p" "$given_file"
}
```

test

```
$ echo 236501 james show 3 4 234247 234125 | sed -n -r 's/^236501 (.*) [0-9]{1,2}( [0-9]{6})*/\1/p'
james show 3
```

Comment: yes i saw this but unfortinatly i can't use this as requested from  my professer

Comment: @newprogrammerha no. i was more alerted because your solution looks more complicated than necessary. if you are told to do in that way, then yeah.